# Jumi (Joomla plugin) breaking PHP global keyword

Tags: php, joomla, global-variables

When I include a PHP script via Jumi, it seems to break the `global` keyword.  Example:

```
<?php

$a = 5;

function foo()
{
        global $a;
        if (isset($a))
                echo $a;
        else
                echo '$a is not set';
}

foo();

?>
```

When I run this PHP script (named test.php) by itself, it correctly prints `5`.  When I run it included via Jumi in a Joomla article solely containing this:

```
{jumi test.php}{/jumi}
```

It prints `$a is not set`.

Is this a bug in Jumi or Joomla, or is there some (un)documented way I'm supposed to work around it?

When I include a PHP script via Jumi, it seems to break the `global` keyword.  Example:

```
<?php

$a = 5;

function foo()
{
        global $a;
        if (isset($a))
                echo $a;
        else
                echo '$a is not set';
}

foo();

?>
```

When I run this PHP script (named test.php) by itself, it correctly prints `5`.  When I run it included via Jumi in a Joomla article solely containing this:

```
{jumi test.php}{/jumi}
```

It prints `$a is not set`.

Is this a bug in Jumi or Joomla, or is there some (un)documented way I'm supposed to work around it?

---

**UPDATE**:  If I mark $a as global in the top scope of the script:

```
<?php

global $a;
$a = 5;
function foo()
{
        global $a;
        if (isset($a))
                echo $a;
        else
                echo '$a is not set';
}
foo();

?>
```

test.php works properly both run by itself and included via Jumi.  My best guess is that Jumi scripts are included in function context, not global context.

Comment: Your global-at-the-top solution doesn't work for me (J1.5 / jumi 1.2.0) :(

Comment: Are you marking it global on both the inside and outside?

Comment: +1 for the update. It is also an issue with sourcerer code but as mentioned elsewhere, it is likely a Joomla "feature"

Answer (score 1):

You may try a little different approach [like this](http://docs.joomla.org/Coding_style_and_standards#Global_Variables), as I believe Joomla limits scope by default

Comment: That link is broken now. [The current Joomla guidelines recommend not using the global keyword at all](https://developer.joomla.org/coding-standards/php-code.html)  
  
`Global variables should not be used. Use static class properties or constants instead of globals, following OOP and factory patterns.`

Answer (score 0):

Working with Jumi is very easy in joomla as it is supported in 2.5, 3.0 versions
I have a solution:

1. Install Jumi.
2. Go to dashboard (Admin panel).
3. Click on *Components -> New*.
4. Enter title.
5. In custom script, you can put your PHP/JavaScript code directly ***or***
6. You can put a filename there using Jumi syntax: `{jumi[directory/filename.php]}`

But remember to create menu for it so that it can appear on `onclick` event of menu.